# How to Check Value if Exists in laravel array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to check if the value in the Table is existed skip it otherwise save it in the table below is the code.

```
 else if(!empty($checkActivity)) 
    {
        //dd($checkActivity);

            foreach($activitydetails->acb as $ac){
        
                $acd=new ActivityFinance();
                 $acd->project_id=$project_id;
                 $acd->account_code=$ac->account_code;
                 $acd->activity_budget=$ac->activity_budget;
                 $acd->exact_title=$ac->exact_title;
                 $acd->created_by=Auth::user()->id;
                 $acd->save();
                }
    
            }
```

if we dd($activity->acb); [image]

and if we dd the $checkActivity it shows the following data [image]
in simple words, there is two arrays, one came from the database and the other from View how to check if the view sent array is in Database?
Thanks

Comment: Pls have a look at the updateOrCreate method: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: it show error "ErrorException
Trying to get property 'account_code' of non-object" the data is $activitydetail->acb[0,1,2,3]->account_code how to loop  here is the function which i changed  if(!empty($checkActivity))  {  $acd=ProjectFinance::upsert([
  'project_id'=>$project_id,
   'account_code'=>$activitydetails->acb->account_code,
    'activity_budget'=>$activitydetails->acb->activity_budget,
   'exact_title'=>$activitydetails->acb->exact_title,
  'created_by'=>Auth::user()->id
                     ]); }

Comment: The error is quite clear, you try to use an array as an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have use the laravel function updateOrCreate() it will check if the entry exist it will ignore or create new , if already in database table then it will update not ID below are the codes

```
ProjectFinance::updateOrCreate([
         'project_id'=>$project_id,
        ],[
      'finance_budget'=>$finance->finance_budget,
      'finance_currency'=>$finance->finance_currency,
       'created_by'=>Auth::user()->id
     ]);
    $upsertActvity=$activitydetails->acb;
 
              foreach($upsertActvity as $up)
                  {

                  ActivityFinance::updateOrCreate([
                     'id'=>$up->id,
                     'project_id'=>$project_id,
                    ],[
                     'account_code'=>$up->account_code,
                     'activity_budget'=>$up->activity_budget,
                     'exact_title'=>$up->exact_title,
                     'created_by'=>Auth::user()->id
                     ]);
```